# Google Map Display Issue

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to do two things from the code below:

1. If the geocode is not successfull don't show the map (so far I've only hidden the error message.)
2. If it is successful only load the address and not the original latlng before reloading the address.

You'll have to excuse all the single quote marks, the javascript loads under a php echo.

Any ideas welcome, ideally I'd like to handle it in the javascript but don't mind a bit of php if needed, I'm looking to use this in a few areas of the site.

```
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.500141,-0.125195);           
    var address = \''.$company.', '.$address_l1.', '.$address_l2.', '.$address_l3.', '.$town.', '.$county.', '.$post_code.', '.$country.'\';                            
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        scrollwheel: false,
        navigationControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    geocoder.geocode( { \'address\': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map, 
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        } else {
            //alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}
</script>           
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
';
```

Comment: have you tried moving the map= new google.maps.. to inside the geocode  success function

Comment: Thanks @gunnx that certainly worked for issue 2, any idea around issue 1? I'm quite new to javascript so this is a little over my head!

Comment: If the geocode does not work because the user's address doesn't validate then to hide the <div id="map_canvas"></div> I'm looking this up online to see if I could run a javascript code in the else statement to hide the div.

Comment: ah ok is there a reason you want to hide it? as it shouldn't be visible unless you are setting css on that div? but otherwise you could do document.getElementById('map_canvas').style.display='none'

Comment: thanks gunnx, I've actually changed the css to not show the div at all and to then run the js "document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.display = \'block\';" to show the div if it runs ok. this way it prevents the div from loading empty until the script hides it if it fails. thanks again for your help.

Comment: ok ive added the basics as a answer if you want to close this. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the map creation into the success function of geocode and use document.getElementById('map_canvas').style.display='block' or none to show/hide the map on fail.